# Sendkeys without element selenium java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple java based selenium code where I would load a page, give the desired values to username & password.

Once the page loads username is already focused but I can enter values into username or password

```
Using MAC - Eclipse
```

I am new to coding sorry so any help would be greatfully received

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://dc1.racbusinessclub.co.uk/login/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("rac-dc");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @Ros5292, once the authentication required box appears I can't enter values into username or password.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the field is already focused, you must specify which element you wish to "send the keys" to. So grab the id of the username field, and *then* use sendKeys, like so:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("userNameInputBox")).sendKeys("rac-dc");
```

Also, worth noting that using Thread.sleep in your scripts is bad practice. If there's something you're waiting for, check for the presence of that element, rather than waiting an arbitrary amount of time.

Edit: Actually, seeing your response above I can see you're trying to interact with an alert popup, which you can do with:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(yourString);
```

Alternatively, you can skip that entirely and navigate to the page with your credentials in the URL - remember not to hard-code these:

`driver.get("http://username:password@http://dc1.racbusinessclub.co.uk/");`

Comment: I am unable to specify which element due to the authentication required box which requires the username & password will not allow me to inspect the element to obtain the id

Comment: If you're using Chrome hit F12 and use the developer tools to identify the element and its id. To do that simply hit CMD+Shift+C on Mac, or CTRL+Shift+C on windows, then click the element.

Comment: driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(yourString);  worked thank you, the issue now is the sendkeys TAB will not work to TAB to the the next element which again i cant not specify which element due to being unable to right click to inspect element to obtain the id

Comment: Then your best bet is to bypass via the URL method I demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

Below is basic way of doing it.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
pause(3);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
button.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

And once logged-in you can assert the url like below

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().endsWith("/yourURL"));
```

You can get username and password id from the browser by Right click on the page and select Inspect.

Comment: The authentication box which requires the username & password will not allow me by right clicking on the page to inspect the element to obtain an id

Comment: You need to have mechanism to know the id's of the elements.